# populate values from database into ObservableList in javafx

Tags: java, database, javafx

How can I properly populate values from a mysql database to an observableList in javafx?  I am using:

`ObservableList<String> deptList=FXCollections.observableArrayList("CSE","ME");`

to manually populate values to observablelist,but I have no idea how to fetch data from a mysql database and populate into observable list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a List from your mysql database, open a database connection to your mysql database and execute your query.  (I'm not going to write this one out for you, because there's plenty of [good](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm) [online](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example).)  Once you have your ResultSet:

```
List<String> listOfSomething;
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    String current = rs.getString("whatever");
    listOfSomething.add(current);
}
```

You can just get a list from your database and convert it to an observable list:

```
List listOfSomething = new ArrayList(ofWhatever);
ObservableList<String> observableListOfSomething = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listOfSomething);
```

Comment: can you explain bit more?I am new to javafx how to get list from database into arraylist?

Comment: That question relates to your database, not to javafx.  What database are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

This is the code used to populate data intoto a **ListView(JavaFX (fxml)).**

```
 private void populateListView {
            try {
                String query = "select * from main_table";
                PreparedStatement prestate = model.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet result = prestate.executeQuery();

                while (result.next()) {
                    String current = result.getString("title");
                    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(current);
                    listview.getItems().addAll(list);
                }

                prestate.close();
                result.close();     
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The answer mentioned in this post is working in my case too.
I am using `postgres` as database.

**creating a table view**

```
@FXML private TableView<AccountMaster> detailstable;
```

**I am getting the details from DB and storing it in a generic list.**

```
List<Student> list = DatabaseClient.getInstance().studentDetailsSearch(id,name);
```

**creating observable list of generic type and then setting the list values in observable list.**

```
ObservableList<AccountMaster> searchDetailsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list );
```

**setting it in table view**

```
detailstable.getItems().addAll(searchDetailsList);
```

With this we can populate values from database into `ObservableList` in `javafx`